# sync mongoDB data to local server for offline mode

Tags: mongodb

I am looking to sync data between devices within a store over a local network, even when that store is disconnected from the internet. When the store is connected to the internet, it can then sync the data with a central copy of the data.

MongoDB Realm Sync relies on devices being connected to the internet to sync data via your Realm cloud service. A device can work offline for hours, and as soon as it gets internet connectivity Realm Sync performs a 2-way sync with the backend Realm service, where changes are persisted in Atlas and synced to other devices but i do not want to use atlas server for mongoDB can it be possible for different server database

i use Mongodb but i did not want to use atlas server for realm to sync data can it be possible without using atlas can we sync data using realm

Comment: No, MongoDB Realm Sync currently cannot be used to achieve local network data synchronization without an Atlas server